# how to set page margins for word document using apache poi?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx, xwpf

I want to set page-margins for word document created using apache poi-3.9.  I found it can be done using `CTPageMar`
 but `CTPageMar` is not being resolved. I am using apache poi-3.9

I tried this

```
CTSectPr sectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
    CTPageMar pageMar = sectPr.addNewPgMar();
    pageMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
    pageMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(1440L));
    pageMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
    pageMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(1440L));
```

Comment: See this thread - http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/How-to-change-margins-of-a-word-document-td5710067.html

Comment: thanks @LittlePanda the code by mark helped but it is working for doc format not for docx. how can I set the margins while creating xwpf document. (the code from link describes setting margins for existing doc)

Comment: You might be using XWPFDocument  nstead of HWPF right?

Comment: yes i am using XWPFDocument

Comment: What happens if you upgrade to Apache POI 3.12 beta 1?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I understand, the problem is not related to the provided code, it is connected with missing `CTPageMar` class.

The source of missing classes problem is clearly explained in [Apache POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025):

> To use the new OOXML file formats, POI requires a jar containing the
>   file format XSDs [...] You can download the jar by hand from the POI Maven Repository.

URL from FAQ is not working, but you can find required jar in [central maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1).

Comment: It's important to note that the ooxml-schemas file that contains everything is not the same as the poi-ooxml-schemas file. From the FAQ: 
"The full jar of all of the schemas is ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar, and it is currently around 15mb. The smaller poi-ooxml-schemas jar is only about 4mb. This latter jar file only contains the typically used parts though."

Answer (score 4):

To resolve the class `CTPageMar` you will have to add the package `org.apache.poi:ooxml-schema` to your classpath. The corresponding JAR contains all schemas. You can find more information [here](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10025).

Comment: still not understand...where to download the org.apache.poi:ooxml-schema without using maven?