# How to change margins when converting with apache poi

Tags: java, pdf, apache-poi, docx

I need to change the margin of the *PDF* file when I convert from Microsoft Word document.

```
public class TestCon {
    public static final String DEST = "./test.pdf";
    public static final String SRC = "./test.docx";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(new File(SRC));

            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(doc );
            CTSectPr addNewSectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
            CTPageMar addNewPgMar = addNewSectPr.addNewPgMar();
            addNewPgMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
            addNewPgMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
            addNewPgMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
            addNewPgMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(DEST));
            PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
            PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**This does not work. The margin does not change in pdf**

---

But when I do this:

```
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(SRC1));
        InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(new File(SRC));

        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(doc );
        CTSectPr addNewSectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
        CTPageMar addNewPgMar = addNewSectPr.addNewPgMar();
        addNewPgMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
        addNewPgMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
        addNewPgMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
        addNewPgMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
        document.write(out);
        out.close();
```

Without converting to PDF, it works.

Comment: I think that your question is solved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29791287/how-to-set-page-margins-for-word-document-using-apache-poi

Comment: "Without converting to PDF it works"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution:

Adjust code part related to `sectPr` and `pgMar` to not add new sections, but reuse them:

```
CTSectPr getSectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().getSectPr();
getSectPr.unsetPgMar();
CTPageMar addNewPgMar = getSectPr.addNewPgMar();
addNewPgMar.setLeft(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
addNewPgMar.setTop(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
addNewPgMar.setRight(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
addNewPgMar.setBottom(BigInteger.valueOf(720L));
// Also good to handle footer and header for more expectable result
addNewPgMar.setFooter(BigInteger.valueOf(0L));
addNewPgMar.setHeader(BigInteger.valueOf(0L));
```

---

### Explanation:

Reason of the issue is that *XDocReport* converter (which is a separate project from *Apache POI*) handles only the first `sectPr` entry of the document.

Your sample will generate [WordprocessingML >>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats) below:

```
<w:sectPr w:rsidR="003F19CD" w:rsidRPr="005E1322">
  <w:pgSz w:h="16838" w:w="11906"/>
  <w:pgMar w:bottom="1134" w:footer="708" w:header="708" w:left="1701" w:right="850" w:top="1134"/>
  <w:cols w:space="708"/>
  <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
</w:sectPr>
<w:sectPr>
  <w:pgMar w:bottom="620" w:left="620" w:right="620" w:top="620"/>
</w:sectPr>
```

Which during conversion to PDF will be handled in the way second `pgmar` (`<w:pgMar w:bottom="620" w:left="620" w:right="620" w:top="620"/>`) will be ignored, since it is part of the second `sectPr`.

Same time in case of saving adjusted document to a new *Word* document `pgMar`s will be merged and you will see needed result (adjusted margin), new *WordprocessingML* will look so:

```
<w:sectPr w:rsidR="003F19CD" w:rsidRPr="005E1322">
  <w:pgSz w:h="16838" w:w="11906"/>
  <w:pgMar w:left="620" w:top="620" w:right="620" w:bottom="620" w:footer="0" w:header="0"/>
  <w:cols w:space="708"/>
  <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
</w:sectPr>
<w:sectPr>
  <w:pgMar w:bottom="620" w:left="620" w:right="620" w:top="620"/>
</w:sectPr>
```

---

Code sample from the **Solution** section will generate single `sectPr` with single `pgMar` so `PDFConverter` will work as needed.

---

### Additional information:

Also need to mention that *XDocReport* provides [configuration possibility >>](https://github.com/opensagres/xdocreport/wiki/XWPFConverterPDFViaIText#ipdfwriterconfiguration):

```
options.setConfiguration(new IPdfWriterConfiguration() {
    public void configure(PdfWriter writer) {
        writer.setPDFXConformance(PdfWriter.PDFA1A);
    }
});
```

But unfortunately it is not possible to handle margins this way (also margin values from the `docx` document will overwrite them after configuration will be done anyway).

---

Additionally below is `pom.xml` dependencies used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>3.15</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.opensagres.xdocreport</groupId>
    <artifactId>fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! At me one more question, and whether it is possible by means of WordprocessingML to make auto hyphenation?

Comment: @crazy_deviL, it supports since it is an XML-based document format developed by _Microsoft_ for _Excel_ and _Word_ documents. Please read this [question >>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46724896/does-the-xwpf-of-apache-poi-support-paragraphs-authohyphenation-feature) for additional details where auto hyphenation configuration is stored. But it doesn't imply that _XDocReport_'s converter will support auto hyphenation (you can test it simply and see that it doesn't).